# Multithreading attempt using Python 3.2.2: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_initialized'"

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm running into a problem with the following Python 3.2.2 code. The code is an attempt to do some timing tests of another application I'm testing. The idea is to have another script (of any variety) get passed into the timer program and make some changes to the environment. That script should run in a separate thread, so that I can start timing from the start of the script instead of the end. The rest of this script times the application's reaction to that script. I've attempted to draw from the `threading` module documentation to create this, and I'm confident that I've read it thoroughly, but I'm consistently running into the following error using this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 669, in start
    if not self._initialized:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_initialized'
```

Here's the thread class definition.

```
import threading, ...

class AsyncScript(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.script = s
    def run(self):
        print ("Beginning script...")
        try:
            os.system("cmd /k " + self.script)
        except:
            sys.exit("Error running script " + self.script)
```

This is called elsewhere in the script by `AsyncScript.start(options.script)`, where the `options` class contains the options passed into the script (using the `argparse` module.)

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong here?

---

Okay, an update. The following (stripped-down) version of the code DOES work, and I'm honestly not sure why -- I don't see the difference.

```
import threading

class AsyncScript(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, s):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.script = s
    def run(self):
        print("This would run script " + self.script)

AsyncScript("sample script path string").start()
```

Output is, appropriately,

> This would run script sample script path string

Aside from the inclusion of `threading.Thread.__init__(self)`, which I had previously included in earlier versions of this code without success, I'm not really sure what's different here. What am I missing?

Comment: Side note: [Never use a bare `except`](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#exceptions). It masks genius bugs and catches some things that aren't errors and probably shouldn't be caught at all. There's almost always a more specific exception to catch.

Comment: Good advice (and a great link!). This is supposed to be pretty simple code, so I'm not too worried about it in this case, but that's definitely a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use threads if you run the script in a separate process anyway. Use `subprocess` instead of `os.system()`.

You don't need to subclass `Thread` to create a thread:

```
Thread(target=func, args=func_args).start()
```

> I'm not really sure what's different here. What am I missing?

There are two differences:

1. `AsyncScript.start(options.script)` vs. `AsyncScript(options.script).start()`.

   `AsyncScript` is a class object. `AsyncScript(options.script)` is an instance of that class.

   `AsyncScript.start(options.script)` calls an unbound `.start` method. It expects its first argument to be an AsyncScript instance not a string `options.script`. The correct way to call a method is `obj.method()`. In your case `obj = AsyncScript(options.script)`.
2. Presense of `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` in the `AsyncScript.__init__()` method.

   If you don't call `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` then Thread's attributes such as `_initialized` are not created/defined.

Comment: Passing the function to `threading.Thread()` makes a lot more sense to me. That should do it -- thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

> This is called elsewhere in the script by `AsyncScript.start(options.script)`

That invokation is wrong. You're calling `threading.Thread`'s nullary (no arguments - not counting `self`) `start` method with your script string as `self`, instead of instanciating your `AsyncScript` class (passing the string to `__init__`) and calling the resulting thread object's `.start()` method. Obviously, a string is not a thread, so the threading code fails when you give it one as `self`. It should probably be `AsyncScript(options.script).start()`

Comment: Just tried calling it with `AsyncScript(options.script).start()`. I now get `AttributeError: 'AsyncScript' object has no attribute '_initialized'`

Comment: @Kudzu: Ah, you're also missing the call to the parent class `__init__`. Use `super().__init__()` (add arguments if you need any, though you override `run` anyway) or `Thread.__init__(self)`.

Comment: Adding `super().__init__()` as the first line of the overridden `__init__` method **might** have worked. I'm now getting a different error: `assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now" / AssertionError: group argument must be None for now` This looks like an error in overriding `threading.Thread` (see [link](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) ) but I'm not certain how to do it correctly.

Comment: @Kudzu: I can neither understand nor reproduce that error. Are you sure there are no arguments to the `super().__init__()` call?

Answer (score 0):

`self.script` isn't initialize in your , but you've got `self.s` - try to use it

Comment: Sorry -- I was attempting to do some last-minute edits of the code to make it clearer here, and ended up missing last line. It's slightly better now.